# How to change the blurred text to normal one in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

In my Unity project, i have two different scenes. And I am using some buttons in both. But the problem is that in one of the scenes i have pretty clear texts on the buttons, however in the other scene button texts look really blurred although i am using exactly same settings for "Button text" as you may see in the picture attached. (Extra info: In the scene which has blurred text, the button is on another button. So the background is another button. However in the other scene, background is a panel). What is the possible reason for this problem?

This is the screenshot for the normal text:
[image]

This one is the blurred one:

[image]

Comment: Are you using the same prefabs?

Comment: If you are not using a prefab, create a prefab using earlier buttons and use it in the second scene.

Comment: I tried to do that, however the result is same.. It's same as creating a local button.

Answer (score 0):

The quality of the text depends on the Font size. Unfortunately, depending of your scene setup, you will need to use small font size although the text takes a large place on the screen. This will result in this blurred effect.

In your case I suspect that the two scene might not use the same scale or canvas size.

Anyway, there is a trick around this:

- Scale down the object with the text component (for instance set it to [0.1, 0.1, 0.1])
- Increase the font size to get to the desired size
- If the text is not visible, set the overflow values to "Overflow"

The more you scale down, to bigger font size you can use, making the text sharper

Comment: Just a second, i think i am missing a point. If i am to scale down the button and increase the font size, how can the text look better although the size of the object is not sufficient to cover the text. If I have a so small button but a font size of 100 ,which is much, probably i will not be able to see the text. What am i missing here?

Comment: Don't scale down the button. just scale down the text element. You should see a button with a very small text. Then increase the font size. You will likely have to set the overflow values of the text to 'Overflow'

Comment: I don't recommend using a scale smaller than 0.25, the result gets VERY aliased. 0.5 should be fine for most use-cases. Also make sure that none of the parent objects in the text's hierarchy have scale, too!

Comment: Did you have any luck making this work? Otherwise tell me and I'll try to be more precise